# What is the right way to write a method which can't be called too frequently?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class with a method that I don't want to be called more than once every five seconds (e.g. it queries a web server which blacklists apps that send queries too frequently).  What is the best way to implement this?

The solution I came up with is to have the method store a time stamp in a static member variable every time it runs via a call to `System.currentTimeMillis()`, and check this time stamp before executing the time sensitive code.  But I'm nervous that there are contingencies I'm not foreseeing, so I wanted to see if there's a standard way to deal with this problem.

Comment: There is no standard way. So you idea with storing last call timestamp is ok.

Comment: I would make this method available to be executed on another thread to not stop the current application for running. In case you want that the method cannot be executed so frequently at application level, then make it `static` and use `static` fields for its execution and your time measurement as well, and synchronize it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The method doesn't have to be static at all; in fact, a *group* of methods could be defined to share the same timeout policy. All such methods (possibly from instances of several different types) would refer to the same static timing data.

Comment: Make that method synchronized and occupy that for 5 secs by thread.

Comment: there is no standard way. your strategy will just work fine

Comment: Another way would be not to block the call but to cache the last result and return it on every call immediately. The cached value would be updated only when the timestamp is too old compared to the current time. This way clients could cheaply call your method when they like, without overloading your server or eating too much bandwidth.

Comment: Why not use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) instead of trying to manage the invocation time on your own?

Answer (score 5):

Use a Guava [RateLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html). Simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  callForeverWithRateLimited();
}

public static void callForeverWithRateLimited() {
  RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(1); // 1 QPS (query per second)
  while (true) {
    if (rateLimiter.tryAcquire()) {
      System.out.println("my rate was limited!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned that it is a web application, your method will share the timestamp variable amongst all calls, i.e. from all active sessions. It does not seem like what you would like to achieve.

A standard "web application" approach will be to put a timer object on the session and write a filter that will manage the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I did not hear of a standard way, but I solved this problem, as i wanted to get ntp time too frequently and the NTP server blocked my requests. So the following code did it for me:

```java
public static long getTime() { 
    // check whether a update should be done
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - updateTime > CLOCK_SYNC_INTERVAL_MS) { 
        // perform the update in a new thread 
        new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                updateClock(); 
            }
        }).start();
    } 
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - updateTime + nts; 
}
```

Comment: Leading Java app servers don't like user spawn threads. They want you to acquire a thread from the container's managed pool.